# Can I project a rectangle to 2D by simply setting Z to 0?

Tags: unity-game-engine, geometry, orthographic

I have a rectangle in 3D space that I need to project to 2D to the screen.
The camera is orthographic, so I figured - can I just set the Z coordinates of the 4 points of the rectangle to 0, so they would splat on the screen?

When I rotate a rectangle on the Y axis for instance, since the camera is orthographic - all I see is the rectangle in front of me getting narrower, because the X and Y components are being altered(along with the Z component).

But if I set the Z to 0 and leave the X and Y, it would still look the same on the orthographic camera.

The question is - is this a viable method? Are there cases where it breaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for building orthographic projection onto OXY plane it is enough to set z=0.

```
matrix is 
(1  0  0  0)
(0  1  0  0)
(0  0  0  0)
(0  0  0  1)
```

When you rotate origin-centered axis-aligned rectangle about axis Y, it's projection will change width, but height remains the same.

Example: right top corner has coordinates `(1, 1, 0)`. After rotation about Y-axis by angle Fi, it has 3d coordinates `(Cos(Fi), 1, Sin(Fi))` and screen coordinates `(Cos(Fi), 1)`